# openshift - nodejs module cannot find module "mosca",

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

We are getting the following error while adding mosca = require("mosca") to my server.js script., any pointers here will be helpful.          ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mosca/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/537dd88d5973ca6907000057/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the package first:

```
npm install mosca
```

Better yet, install it and add it to your `package.json`:

```
npm install --save mosca
```

Comment: Hi I have already added 'mosca' module in package.json, below are the details of package.json   "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
 "jade": "~1.3.1",
    "mosca": "~0.20.1",
 "mongodb":"~1.4.5"
  },

Comment: Adding it to your `package.json` will not install the package - you need to run `npm install`

Comment: Can you please detail how this particular module can be installed separately. Other packages in package.json installed automatically by openshift.

Comment: @ASESA That's literally what I did in my answer.  Did you try it?

Comment: I did' and noticed openshift installed mosca, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now, Some how mosca module is not being installing, so I have installed locally and copied content to node_modules